# pam_tally2 causing unwanted lockouts with SCOM or Nervecenter

Tags: linux, redhat, pam

We use pam_tally2 in our system-auth config file which works fine for users. With services such as SCOM or Nervecenter it causes lockouts.

Same behavior on RHEL5 and RHEL6

This is /etc/pam.d/nervecenter

```
#%PAM-1.0
# Sample NerveCenter/RHEL6 PAM configuration
# This PAM registration file avoids use of the deprecated pam_stack.so module.
auth         include    system-auth
account      required   pam_nologin.so
account      include    system-auth
```

and this is /etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
auth       sufficient     pam_centrifydc.so
auth       requisite      pam_centrifydc.so deny
account    sufficient     pam_centrifydc.so
account    requisite      pam_centrifydc.so deny
session    required       pam_centrifydc.so homedir
password   sufficient     pam_centrifydc.so try_first_pass
password   requisite      pam_centrifydc.so deny
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=6 onerr=fail
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so
password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minclass=3  minlen=8 lcredit=1 ucredit=1 dcredit=1 ocredit=1 difok=1
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow try_first_pass use_authtok remember=8
password    required      pam_deny.so
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

The login does work but it also triggers the pam_tally counter up until it hits 6 "false" logins.

Is there any pam-ninjas around that could spot the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Reading through some of the bugs and issues

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707660
- http://www.redhat.com/archives/pam-list/2008-July/msg00017.html

pam_tally2 needs to be specified for **auth** and **account**. This will reset its counter when the login was successful.

Changing it to the following has fixed the problem

```
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=6 onerr=fail
account     required      pam_tally2.so
```

Main reason was that SCOM was trying different authentication methods. While some failed one was successful. The problem was that the counter never reset itself.